Remote desktop session host excessive retransmissions on port 3389 (RDP protocol)
We have an issue with a RemoteApp program we use in my company, one which many users use during the day all connecting to the same RDS Collection.
I have run Wireshark on the RDS that hosts these application sessions and there are excessive retransmissions from each PC on our LAN that is connecting to the RemoteApp, which is hosted off this RDS Host server. The retransmissions are mainly FROM the host and TO the client.
I am wondering what could be causing this. We have a large lag in traffic and functionality in the app and receive complaints about latency on clicks, screens fade slowly, and also clicking into a new screen, then a few seconds later having it cut back to the previous screen as if they never left).
I know it might have something to do with not receiving an ACK in time.
Short of running wireshark and identifying  an abnormal number of retransmissions too and from the host (and i know its through the remote app as the users on my site have no other way to access it but through the remoteapp shortcut on their PC's), I haven't tried much as i don't know really what direction to go in. Speed tests on the network look good, and tracert only goes over 1 hop.
Ping is 180 ms which could be one factor. From my local machine to the RDS host, and vice versa.
But I'm hoping this is not the main reason and could use some guidance.

You already indicated that you know that the endpoint is not sending the ACK. The reason for that is low cost connections typically have much lower upload performance. The network path back to the server is oversubscribed and congested. 180 ms is nearly unusable and that's what you need to fix. The problem is between the server and the endpoint.

Are the clients and the servers connected to the same physical network? It sounds like they are. If you have 180ms latency between the clients and the servers, in the same local network, then you need to find and fix that problem. That much latency for remote desktop services is almost unusable.

@joeqwerty so for the network where im located, we are a global company that has a Hybrid AAD environment. We in the US are connecting back to an on prem server in New Zealand. the RDS server is a Virtual server hosted on a Hyperv Physical server that is located back in NZ. Our network is laid out where we communicate to our firewall, through a BOVPN back to New Zealand's firewall, and then through that too the RDS Server.
